# Security vulnerability for mobile applications

Tags: security, mobile

I would like to know if the security vulnerabilities for web based applications such as the ones due to poor input validation such as 
SQL injection
XML injection
XSS 
CSRF
Click Jacking (Frame bursting)

Since the mobile app runs in its own sandbox environment, i would have thought that the browser specific vulnerabilities would not be applicable.
OWASP does not list out these as part of their top 10 list and I wanted to understand if there is a scenario where these can pose a issue for mobile apps

Answer (score 0):

Most of the vulns described in the OWASP top 10 are attacks against the server. E.g SQL injection, XML injection, Java deserialization, CSRF and others.

Thus it doesn't matter if the client is a browser or a mobile App. The attacker can craft their requests with any tool they want.

There are specific vulns related to mobile application on the client side. These are described in the [Owasp mobile app top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Mobile_Security_Project)